# Compiler Inference and OverloadedStrings

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have the following code.

```
data RI a = Union (RI a) (RI a) | Kleene (RI a) |
            Concat (RI a) (RI a) | Const a | Empty | EmptySet deriving (Show)

instance Monoid (RI a) where
  mempty = EmptySet
  mappend = Union

instance IsString (RI Char) where
  fromString s = either (error "Incorrect Parse") (id) (getRE s)

instance IsString (RI Char -> RI Char) where
  fromString s = (\r -> mappend (fromString s) r)

runR :: RI Char -> String -> Bool 
runR r s = True

chain :: String -> Bool
chain = runR ("a" "b")
```

Upon running the code I get:

```
re.hs:46:15:
    No instance for (IsString (a0 -> RI Char))
       arising from the literal ‘"a"’
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    Note: there is a potential instance available:
      instance IsString (RI Char -> RI Char) -- Defined at re.hs:39:10
    In the expression: "a"
    In the first argument of ‘runR’, namely ‘("a" "b")’
    In the expression: runR ("a" "b")

re.hs:46:19:
    No instance for (IsString a0) arising from the literal ‘"b"’
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance IsString (RI Char -> RI Char) -- Defined at re.hs:39:10
      instance IsString (RI Char) -- Defined at re.hs:36:10
      instance IsString [Char] -- Defined in ‘Data.String’
      ...plus two others
    In the first argument of ‘"a"’, namely ‘"b"’
    In the first argument of ‘runR’, namely ‘("a" "b")’
    In the expression: runR ("a" "b")
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Adding an annotation to chain solves the problem but it is ugly.

```
chain = runR ("a" ("b" :: RI Char))
```

The question is, why can't the compiler work this out for itself? The first argument of `runR` has the type `RI Char` so somehow we must evaluate `"a" "b"` to this type. From the instances I have defined, the only way to do this is to use the `RI Char -> RI Char` instance for `"a"` and the `RI Char` instance for `"b". Unfortunately, the compiler does not do this.

Comment: The same reason `(read "a") (read "b")` wouldn't work. You need some way of determining what class instance to select. But the type of `fromString` is `IsString a => String -> a`; the class parameter is only mentioned in the output, not the input, so there is no way for the input to pick an instance. Just because there is only one set of instances which will produce a valid program *in scope*, doesn't mean that only one set of instances will ever exist. The simplest workaround is to have a newtype for `RI Char -> RI Char`

Comment: Suppose you have `instance IsString (String -> RI Char) where ...`. Then `"a" "b"` would be ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, as my friend point out.. "why don't you just write IsString instances for literally everything and write your program as a sequence of strings". The above code has been rewritten to avoid this abuse.